# How Do I Make Rounded Edges On A Toolbar Using CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css, toolbar

I'm trying to figure out how to use either CSS, HTML, or both to turn a toolbar into a toolbar with rounded corners. Here's the CSS:

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #333333;
}
</style>
```

Can anyone show me what to add to this so that the corners of the toolbar become rounded?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would serve ([Demo Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Vn5d/2/))?

```
#toolbar{
    border: 2px solid orange;
    padding: 10px 40px; 
    background: black;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

This CSS is in fact from w3schools' page on border-radius css rule: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: changed to a smaller radius :) @moneyman849, if it's not this, maybe you should provide more info on what you are looking for...

Comment: border-top-right-radius , border-bottom-right-radius : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-top-right-radius.asp , http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-bottom-right-radius.asp

Answer (score 0):

## CSS3 Border Radius: browser support

Since [Border radius Support](http://caniuse.com/border-radius) is quite spread all over the browsers, except IE8, you can use it, but remember the vendor-prefix:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
```

### Example

Here is a simple example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mykisscool/u5U57/).